# Query on import feature in python

Tags: python

For a program,
I have three files `dice.py` `hog.py`  `ucb.py` sitting in same folder.

```
""" hog.py"""
from dice import four_sided_dice, six_sided_dice
from ucb import interact

def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided_dice, who='Boss Hogg'):
    """Calculate WHO's turn score after rolling DICE for NUM_ROLLS times.

    num_rolls:  The number of dice rolls that will be made; at least 1.
    dice:       A function of no args and returns an integer outcome.
    who:        Name of the current player, for commentary.
    """
    score = 0
    assert type(num_rolls) == int, 'num_rolls must be an integer.'
    assert num_rolls > 0, 'Must roll at least once.'
    for i in range(0, num_rolls):
        temp = dice()
        score += temp
        print(temp)
    return score
```

---

```
"""dice.py"""

from random import randint

def make_fair_dice(sides):
    """Return a die that returns 1 to SIDES with equal chance."""
    assert type(sides) == int and sides >= 1, 'Illegal value for sides'
    def dice():
        return randint(1,sides)
    return dice

four_sided_dice = make_fair_dice(4)
six_sided_dice = make_fair_dice(6)
```

In `hog.py`, one of the syntax is,

```
from dice import four_sided_dice, six_sided_dice
```

When i say,

```
>>> python -i hog.py
```

all the names defined in hog.py module get appended to `__main__` module's global frame.

My question:

When the above import statement gets encountered in `hog.py`,

1)
Does Python load `function make_fair_dice()` defined in `dice.py` as part of `__main__` module? or separate module?

2)
how does python interpreter know that, `dice.py` file is in same folder? What should be done, if i need to pick `dice.py` from different folder?

Comment: Please consider [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). Also, you can test point 1 - what happens if you try to call the function `make_fair_dice()` directly?

Comment: You should consider giving your questions better titles, too - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. "Query on ..." is not very helpful - try to succinctly summarise the actual question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here is my observation for testing point 1, After i run `>>> python -i hog.py`, All definitions written in `hog.py` file are part of `__main__` module. In `hog.py` file, When i say `import` any name(function) from `ucb.py` or `dice.py` module and call that function, that function is executing in the scope of `ucb` or `dice` module respectively but not in the scope of `__main__` module. So, In above syntax in query, imports with names are like pointers to functions in the module outside `__main__` module. All this is verified using the value of global variable `__name__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe search path of modules, is checked in current dir, then in PYTHONPATH, then in installation-dependent default path.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following script:

```
from dice import four_sided_dice, six_sided_dice

print four_sided_dice() # OK
print six_sided_dice()  # OK

my_dice = make_fair_dice(8) # NameError: name 'make_fair_dice' is not defined
```

Since you explicitly import only two names: `four_sided_dice` and `six_sided_dice`, the name `make_fair_dice` will not be available, thus causing a `NameError`.

However, since this is an import statement, the entire `dice.py` module gets executed. That means procedure `make_fair_dice` is loaded. It is just not available to call directly. Now, if you implicitly import the dice module, then everything is available:

```
import dice
my_dice = dice.make_fair_dice(8) # OK
```

As for your second question, please take a look at the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) documentation.